# Give an error message and restart loop if user input is not the correct datatype in java while continue if it is?

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner, mismatch

Hey this is a small part of my program that I'm having big issues with. I want the program to give the user an error message and start the loop from the beginning if the input is not an integer, while I want it to continue into the switch/case if it is an integer. This is what I got so far, but it is not working since I get the inputmismatchexception if its incorrect and it doesn't continue in to the switch/case if it is correct?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Dog> doglist = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean running = true;

    while (running) {
        System.out.println("\n************************************");
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to the kennel club!");
        System.out.println("\n************************************");
        System.out.println("\n[1] Register new dog");
        System.out.println("[2] Print out list");
        System.out.println("[3] Increase age");
        System.out.println("[4] Remove dog");
        System.out.println("[5] Quit program");
        System.out.println("\n************************************");
        System.out.println("\nChoose: ");

        int option = 0;
        boolean inputOk = false;
        do {
            try {
                option = myscan.nextInt();
                inputOk = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Option must be a number");
                myscan.nextLine(); // to consume the \n that remains at the end of the line after using nextInt();
            }
        }
        while (!inputOk);

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Write name:");
                String name = myscan.next();
                System.out.println("Write race:");
                String race = myscan.next();
                System.out.println("Age:");
                int age = myscan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Weight:");
                double weight = myscan.nextDouble();

                Dog dog = new Dog(name, race, age, weight);

                doglist.add(dog);

                break;

            case 2:

                System.out.println("Minimum length of tail:");
                double userInput1 = myscan.nextDouble();

                for (Dog d : doglist) {
                    if (d.getTailLength() >= userInput1) {
                        System.out.println(d.toString());
                    }
                }

                break;

            case 3:

                System.out.println("Name of dog:");
                String userInput2 = myscan.next();
                int flag = 0;
                for (Dog d : doglist) {
                    if (d.getName().equals(userInput2)) {
                        d.increaseAge();
                        d.increasetailLength();
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (flag == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Error, can't find dog with name:" + userInput2);
                }

                break;

            case 4:

                System.out.println("Name of dog:");
                String userInput3 = myscan.next();

                Dog dogToRemove = null;

                for (Dog d : doglist) {
                    if (d.getName().equals(userInput3)) {
                        dogToRemove = d;
                        System.out.println("Dog is removed");
                    }
                }

                if (dogToRemove == null) {
                    System.out.println("Error, can't find dog with name: " + userInput3);
                } else {
                    doglist.remove(dogToRemove);
                }

                break;

            case 5:

                running = false;//Avslutar loopen och därmed programmet
                System.out.println("Program finshed");
                break;

            default:

                System.out.println("Error, choose between [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]");//Felmeddelande om valet är någon annan siffra än de som menyn innehåller
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a do-while to read the option catching the InputMismatchException:

```
int option = 0;
boolean inputOk = false;
do{
    try {
        option = myscan.nextInt();
        inputOk = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException  e) {
        System.out.println("Error, this is not an integer.");
        myscan.nextLine(); // to consume the \n that remains at the end of the line after using nextInt();
    }
}while (!inputOk);
```

This way it will loop until you get a valid number.

**EDIT**

If you want to print the menu again then you can do this: in your original code, change the break statement with a continue statement and also include a call to the `nextLine` method [to consume the remaining \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo):

```
int option = 0; // don't read the value directly before validating that is actually an integer value or you will get the InputMismatchException

if (!myscan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Error, this is not an integer:");
    myscan.nextLine(); // consume the \n
    continue; // loop again
} else {
    option = myscan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I added this, but same thing is still happening. It does not continue to the switch statement if it is correct, and crashes if it isn't

Comment: Did you remove the if statement after trying this suggestion?

Comment: yes, this works as long as its correct, but it does not return to the loop after the error message?

Comment: Can you please add at least the whole while loop?

Comment: i added the whole class so you can see it now :)

Comment: I have run the code with this answer and it works http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/1065928. It loops until you get a valid Integer. Then it continues to the switch statement executing the proper case block depending on the option.

Comment: yes it works, but it doesn't restart the loop from while(running), if the user input is wrong you get the error message but then nothing happens right?

Comment: What happens is that is expecting you to introduce an option again.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. That could also work, but do you know how to start from the menu again?

Comment: Ok. See my edit. Here is a test with the new version http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/1065928

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of grabbing and expecting an integer when you aren't guaranteed one, simply grab whatever the next line is and determine if the value entered is an integer with a regular expression like this

```
      while(running)
      {
          inputFromUser = myscan.nextLine();
          int option = -1; //some default invalid value
          boolean doSwitch = false;

          if(inputFromUser.matches("\\d+"))
          {
              option = Integer.parseInt(inputFromUser);
              doSwitch = true;
          }
          else{
              System.out.println("Incorrect input was received - " + inputFromUser);
          }

          if(doSwitch)
          {
              //switch logic
          }
      }
```

Comment: the option in the switch statement doesn't work this way, since it is being initialized inside an if statement?

Comment: the previous would have worked but if you want to initialize in the beginning then ask for input and then try the switch you can. This will work perfectly fine as well with the changes @mackanmorre